# Can't run kivy file on Komodo

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, komodo, kivy-language

I'm trying to run a Kivy python file on Komodo IDE (for Mac) but its giving me this error 
`import kivy
ImportError: No module named kivy` although if I drag-drop the file on the Kivy app its running normally,

any ideas ?, thanks

Comment: did you try to `sudo pip install kivy` on the terminal yet? sometimes the installation is not in the python path, so python doesn't see it.

Comment: Maybe the IDE uses a different python installation (change path to get it or install kivy there) or... add aditional import folder as the answer tells you. To check for different installtions just open console and check versions. If not sufficient, check `pip list`. Made me chuckle - Kivy on Komodo(re) :D

Answer (score 0):

Try going to **Edit > Preferences > Languages > Python > Additional Python Import Directories**, and adding the directory where Kivy is installed. I am not sure on a Mac where this would be. To find out, in a python interpreter (or elsewhere - wherever you are able to successfully import `kivy`) do:

```
>>> import kivy
>>> kivy.__file__
```

and add the directory one up from `kivy/` in that path through the Komodo settings as described above.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for Komodo code intelligence.  Run time is still limited to PYTHONPATH.  To run a script that's using Kivy, even in your command line, the kivy source has to be on your PYTHONPATH.

You can add items to your PYTHONPATH in Komodo using **Edit > Preferences > Environment** then create a *New* environmental variable to append the kivy installation location to your `$PYTHONPATH`, ie `$PYTHONPATH:install/location/kivy`.

If you don't mind having it in your system though, I'd just do what @tuan333 suggest above, install it using pip, then make sure you're using THAT Python interpreter in Komodo.